# Как расширить видимую область в терминале phpstorm

Tags: phpstorm, консоль

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно расширить видимую область в терминале пхпшторма ? Когда ввожу длинные команды или вызываю например вывод всех роутов в ларавели, часть текста не отображается в окне, хотя он там есть.

На изображении нагляднее о проблеме.

[image: наглядное отображение проблемы]

Comment: Какую версию PhpStorm вы используете? Попробуйте workaround из https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-117552#focus=streamItem-27-1020577.0-0 - может помочь

Comment: @lena большое вам спасибо! Я уже и не надеялся решить эту проблему, ваша ссылка помогла :) Версия шторма 10.0.2. Можете оформить как ответ, отмечу галочкой :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже на [IDEA-117552](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-117552), эта проблема решена в последних версиях PhpStorm.

Попробуйте установить `cmd.exe /K "mode con:cols=500 lines=9999&cmd.exe"` в качестве shell path в настройках терминала (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-117552#focus=streamItem-27-1020577.0-0) - должно помочь